# Char data type and while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, char, character

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    char txt;
    cout << "Enter text (Enter '.' to quit)";

    while ( txt != '.')
    {
        cin >> txt;
        cout << txt;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm a beginner in C++. In class we were taught that `char` only holds one character. However, when I inserted `cin << txt` inside a `while` loop it suddenly can take more than one character. How is it possible that `char` can now suddenly store more than one character? Can someone provide a link where I can read more about this?

Comment: It does not hold more than one value, it gets a new value, prints this value out and repeats.

Comment: @NegativeTension it's buffered in cin's buffer so after assignment cin clears what it assigned from its buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Char is not taking more than one values. Your while loop logic is making it appear that it takes multiple values as input and then return that as output. 
Suppose like input is: hello.
So  execution will be like this

- char var will h as input and then  followed by h as output.
- Followed by e & so on till '. ' after which while loop will stop.

So in actual it's doing one character input one character output in succession which is making you appear that it is behaving like string.

If you want see detailed working then use a debugging tool for understanding or insert delay between input , output & next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on here is that when you are inputting the char, you are only inputting one character, but all of the other characters in your string are staying in the buffer. if you change:

```
cout << txt;
```

to

```
cout << txt << '\n';
```

then it will print the character and then a newline. You see you'll get the individual characters on each line.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

char is char 1 holds only byte it the smallest data type in c++ as bool.

in your example:
you enter a text instead of a single char so in fact this text is buffered in cin's buffer and then flushes it to txt. txt is a single char so it assigns the first character to it ok. but the buffer is still containing other characters and as long as as you are in infinite-conditioned loop cin assigns the second character to txt instead of the previous and son on until the las character.

to get what I say remove cout from inside loop and make it outside:

char txt;

```
cout << "Enter text (Enter '.' to quit)";

while ( txt != '.')
    cin >> txt;

cout << txt; // you'll get only the last character '.'
```

the reason:

let's say you enter: "Hello."
it is equal to:

```
cin>>txt; // H
cin>>txt; // e
cin>>txt; // l
cin>>txt; // l
cin>>txt; // o
cin>>txt; // .
```

now the txt is assigned the '.' which is the last input character